# keep jquery dialog open after postback in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm still learning MVC
Showing a grid of employees with Edit, Details, Delete links.

On Edit click:
I'm opening a jQuery Dialog using below code and calling an MVC action.
Action URL is in url parameter in load function.

```
 $(".edit").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("editing");
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Edit Details',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 455,
                width: 550,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);

                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
```

I've put some server side validations. On clicking Update button after changing employee details (inside modal dialog opened with Edit link above).
no matter server side validation fail or pass, modal dialog is getting closed which i know is natural in a postback.

I want to know what is correct way to **again open that jquery modal Dialog** if server side validation fails with error message showing the reason to user.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag in the response to know if you need to open the dialog and display the errors but: **this is not a good practice**

it could be better if you do a GET with jquery and then you can handle the response and close the dialog if there aren't errors.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if below solution has some issue:

I modified my jQuery dialog code to make a ajax call to Update the details instead of Submitting the form.

Also, modified Action method to return JsonResult instead of ActionResult

```
  $(".edit").on("click", function (e) {
        alert("editing");
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Edit Details',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 455,
            width: 550,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save" : function(){
                    $.post("Student/Edit", $("form").serialize(), function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            alert("data saved");
                            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
                            window.location.href = "Student/Index";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("not saved");
                        }

                    });
                }
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load(url);

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```